# TFS and RTC - can both be used for both Java and .NET development

Tags: version-control, build-process, build-automation, sdlc, alm

Both Microsoft's Team system and IBM's Rational Team Concert have similar features and functions.  Both claim to be able to support either Java or .NET developers with their favorite IDE.   Do you have any experience that shows one is better than the other for a one solution that works for all?  Is there any key differences (features) between them that makes you favor one over the other?  How good is the interoperability for either one?

Just trying to separate the marketing from the reality with people that have lots of knowledge and experience with both products.

TIA,

Scott

Comment: As a source control system, TFS will support any source. However I wonder if you could post a link where you saw Microsoft specifically mention Java (other than through Teamprise).

Comment: You are correct, that the Java IDE (eclipse) integration is through the third party Teamprise and not native to VSTS.

Comment: Just curious as to ifg you have an answer of your own now that it's been almost a year.  We're looking at what we want to use for ALM, and both TFS and RTC are on the table for our .NET team (primarily because our IBM RPG development team is going to be using RTC.)

Answer (score 0):

Team Explorer Everywhere (for Eclipse)
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25125

Team Explorer
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=329

TFS version control can manage any files you want.
TFS build server can build anything you want, you can use it to launch Ant or Maven or javac.exe if you want.
TFS work items are language agnostic.
TFS test cases are language agnostic.  You don't have to use MSTest.

There is no reason why you couldn't use the whole suite of TFS for developing Java in Eclipse. (Microsoft has even bent over backwards to enable the scenario.)